# What can we do against strategic downvotes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes

Sometimes a downvote comes just with an excuse from a person who answered to the same question. I don't want to make a specific example, neither to accuse a specific person, so I'll make an example:

- `A` answers the question, there are syntax errors on his questions;
- People make him notice the syntax errors and `A` edits the answer;
- `B` answers to the question, everything is OK with his answer;
- `B` makes `A` notice that he is returning an area of memory which is on the stack, so the code isn't correct, and he downvotes;
- A edits the answer, but downvotes `B` too, with an excuse like that he is casting the result of `malloc`, and that this cast is useless.

So in this case we can't demonstrate that `A` downvotes to `B` just with an excuse, since there is an appearent reason to his downvote. But if usually `A` downvotes for big errors, then he now downvotes for a small error, or for a non-error, a metter of personal taste like casting or not casting the result of malloc. He wouldn't do the same if the answer wasn't competing with him, but no one can demonstate this.

Now -2 points are nothing, but this can happen several times. It may also happen that an user downvotes for wrong reasons, so how do we demonstrate that we are right in that case? Is there a way to debate on the downvote even tough -2 points are nothing? The reason is mainly to be politically correct, not because I care about losing few points.

Comment: You *cannot* divine whom downvotes or why. Stop worrying about it.

Comment: And before you complain about getting down-voted here: [voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: I never complained about down voting.Take it as if I asked to solve a math problem that has no solution.

Comment: It also happens that people upvote for the wrong reason. That is a much bigger (+10) problem.

Comment: Just pre-empting because a lot of people come and ask questions here without reading the FAQ (myself included, way back when) and then get discouraged or take offense when their idea gets down-voted.

Comment: I am sorry, but sincerely FAQ is boring and I prefer downvotes rather than reading it.

Comment: Heh! I can't help but sympathize with that attitude. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to debate a downvote.

If a downvote doesn't seem to have any merit (double-check your answer to make sure you didn't make a mistake), just ignore it. It happens to everyone from time to time.

Comment: I wanted to downvote this answer to demonstrate downvotes happen from time to time, but instead, I decided to upvote it. :P

Comment: And community wiki takes all the fun out of strategic downvoting. Damn you.

Comment: Don't be ChrisF.